# Why isnt my second form loading on startup? Is it stuck?

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets, events, tcp

So I just want to make it clear that I am very new to Tcp / IP programming in C#. Also, I've changed the IP's in the question to not match the ones in my project due not not wanting to leak it.

When ever I start the project it should open 2 forms (Client & server)
but for some reason it only opens the Client winform application.
(I've changed the start method in the project settings to start both)

My best guess would be that its stuck on trying to start the TcpListener when ever I call it in the Form_Load event.

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Here is the server (the one that doesnt start)

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;


namespace SimpleServer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        string rd;
        byte[] b1;
        string v;
        int m;
        //TcpListener list;

        Int32 port = 8080;
        Int32 port1 = 8080;


        IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.1");

        private void BrowseBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                textBox1.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
                TcpListener list = new TcpListener(localAddr, port1);
                //list = new TcpListener(port1);
                list.Start();
                TcpClient client = list.AcceptTcpClient();
                Stream s = client.GetStream();
                b1 = new byte[m];
                s.Read(b1, 0, b1.Length);
                File.WriteAllBytes(textBox1.Text + "\\" + rd.Substring(0, rd.LastIndexOf('.')), b1);
                list.Stop();
                client.Close();
                statusLabel.Text = "File Received......";
            }
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.1"); //changed it from my main ip
            TcpListener list = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);
            //TcpListener list = new TcpListener(port);
            list.Start();
            TcpClient client = list.AcceptTcpClient();
            MessageBox.Show("Client trying to connect");
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
            rd = sr.ReadLine();
            v = rd.Substring(rd.LastIndexOf('.') + 1);
            m = int.Parse(v);
            list.Stop();
            client.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the client source code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;

namespace SimpleClient
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        string n;
        byte[] b1;
        OpenFileDialog op;

        private void browseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            op = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (op.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string t = textBox1.Text;
                t = op.FileName;
                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(textBox1.Text = op.FileName);
                n = fi.Name + "." + fi.Length;
                TcpClient client = new TcpClient("22.232.23.22", 8080);
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
                sw.WriteLine(n);
                sw.Flush();
                statusLabel.Text = "File Transferred....";
            }
        }

        private void sendBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient("22.232.23.22", 8080);
            Stream s = client.GetStream();
            b1 = File.ReadAllBytes(op.FileName);
            s.Write(b1, 0, b1.Length);
            client.Close();
            statusLabel.Text = "File Transferred2....";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: nowhere in your code can i see where you are trying to show your second form

Comment: I would add an else if condition for this `if (op.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)` what if the user clicks `No || Cancel` for starters. Also have you stepped thru your code

Comment: What it should be doing is open 2 projects and not just one.
And im not done with the project im just trying to resolve this first, So why isnt my other project loading, did you check the Load_Event?

Comment: voted to close under why isnt my code working

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one startup project in a solution... Right Click Project in Solution Explorer and choose "Set as Startup Project"

When you deploy the exe's you will have to start the server Exe either manually, by Scheduled Task or better yet make the Server Exe run as a Service.

Another way you could do it is `System.Diagnostic.Process.Start("..\bin\Debug\SimpleServer.exe");`

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions, I'm guessing you're a little confused how to setup both a client Exe and a server Exe to both run so they can communicate

Comment: Well, If I remove the Form1_Load completly, it lets me start both if them (both of them being these guys) https://imgur.com/a/EOR49 so it has to eb something with the load function right =?

Comment: Look in both Program.cs files, put a break points in there and step through the code, if your gut feeling is telling you it's stuck starting the TcpListener then put breakpoints around those code lines. Maybe also check out some sample client/server projects on like CodeProject to see how they are setup because I'm guessing it's the setup and multiple startup projects that you just need to see an example

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that it couldnt connect because the ip adresses didnt match in the client and the server. Both had to be a IPV4 adress.